# How to show a div only after the second session on the website

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show a div only after the user has navigated to the website a second time via a second session (not by refreshing or visiting another page). But for some reason the code changes the value on refresh and not on session end.

```
function checkCookies() {
    var showPopup = getCookie("showPopup");
    if (showPopup === null) {
        console.log("first time");
        setCookie("showPopup", 2, 30);
    }
    else {
        if (showPopup > 1) {
            console.log(">1");
        }
        else {
            console.log("<1");
        }
    }
}
checkCookies();

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    setCookie("showPopup", 2, 30);
}
```

Comment: by second session do u mean second tab ? in the same browser ?

Comment: I would make the check against a known value [like 1], and not null.

Comment: How do you handle the website server-side? For example if it's in PHP you could use the PHP session to set a client cookie based on the session id. If the cookie is absent, it's the first visit, if present and the id has changed, it's a new session